# A função retorna undefined. O que está errado?

Tags: javascript, funções, return

```js
var pulaLinha = function() {
  document.write("<br>");
}

var mostra = function(frase) {
  document.write(frase);
  pulaLinha();
}

var calculaIMC = function(altura, peso) {
  var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
  return;
}

var alturaDoUsuario = prompt("Sua altura? ");
var pesoDoUsuario = prompt("Seu peso? ");

var imcDoUsuario = calculaIMC(alturaDoUsuario, pesoDoUsuario);
mostra("O seu imc é: " + imcDoUsuario);
```

Comment: E este `return;`?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

É bem claro, o código está retornando nada, se quer que retorne algo tem que escrever isto. A função faz um cálculo ali dentro e abandona este resultando. Um `return` retorna nada, um `return <expressão>` retorna a expressão.

```js
function calculaIMC(altura, peso) { return peso / (altura * altura); }

console.log("O seu imc é: " + calculaIMC(prompt("Sua altura? "), prompt("Seu peso? ")));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Bmi2.js).

Comment: Ok! Muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Acho que seria também interessante mencionar que os `prompts` e consequentes variáveis `alturaDoUsuario` e `pesoDoUsuario` no código da pergunta são `strings` e apenas funciona corretamente devido as conversões implícitas que são feitas.

Comment: @Isac fica o seu comentário como esse alerta :)